# How do you integrate $(2+x)(1+x)√(5-4x)dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Hello so far I've tried using wolfram and an answer popped up, however since I have the premium version I was able to look up the steps required, my question is where did this $u^2$ suddenly appear if $u=√(5-4x)$?
[image: Here is the picture]

I am confused as to where $√(5-4x)$ was able to be eliminated and somehow be replaced with $u^2$. If someone can show me the way that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: $$
du =  - \frac{2}{{\sqrt {5 - 4x} }}dx =  - \frac{2}{u}dx \Leftrightarrow  dx=- \frac{1}{2}udu
$$

Comment: When you change variables, you're adding a term, what it's added when changing $dx$ to $du$, which is in the image there. That's what's adding the exponent in $u$.

Comment: ah i see thank you both of u i didn't know u could do it like that. Thank You! Mind writing your answer down in a post so that I can close my question as answered, Thanks!